# Background process is not being terminated by SIGINT when executed via ssh

Tags: ssh, kill, background-process, signals, nohup

I was experimenting with ssh, nohup, bg etc. I started a tail process in remote using

```
$ ssh remotehost '{ nohup tail -f ut.log &> /dev/null < /dev/null &} && echo $!'
```

It successfully started the background tail process as expected, print it's pid and exited. Then I logged on to remote machine and checked the pid.

```
$ ps -o pid,tid,ppid,pgid,sid,class,nice,rtprio,pri,sched,cmd,tty,tpgid,cgroup,stat,flags,sig,sigcatch,sigignore,sigmask,euid,ruid,egid,rgid,ouid -p 27876
  PID   TID  PPID  PGID   SID CLS  NI RTPRIO PRI SCH CMD                         TT       TPGID CGROUP                      STAT F          PENDING           CAUGHT          IGNORED          BLOCKED  EUID  RUID  EGID  RGID OWNER
27876 27876     1 27847 27847 TS    0      -  19   0 tail -f ut.log              ?           -1 12:pids:/user.slice/user-28 S    0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000007 0000000000000000 28889 28889 10005 10005 28889
```

But after that, if I try to end the process using `kill`, it is not terminating with `SIGINT` or `SIGQUIT`, but it is terminating with `SIGTERM`.

However, if I run the exact same command directly on the remote machine, and try to end the process using `kill`, it is terminating just with `SIGINT`.

```
$ { nohup tail -f ut.log &> /dev/null < /dev/null &} && echo $!
```

```
$ ps -o pid,tid,ppid,pgid,sid,class,nice,rtprio,pri,sched,cmd,tty,tpgid,cgroup,stat,flags,sig,sigcatch,sigignore,sigmask,euid,ruid,egid,rgid,ouid -p 28111
  PID   TID  PPID  PGID   SID CLS  NI RTPRIO PRI SCH CMD                         TT       TPGID CGROUP                      STAT F          PENDING           CAUGHT          IGNORED          BLOCKED  EUID  RUID  EGID  RGID OWNER
28111 28111 24889 28111 24889 TS    0      -  19   0 tail -f ut.log              pts/45   28128 12:pids:/user.slice/user-28 S    0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 28889 28889 10005 10005 28889
```

Why it is happening like that?

**EDIT:** I think it may be because of the sigignore mask present in the former. But both processes are started by exact same command. Then how both processes have different masks? I used `nohup`, hence I expect mask for `SIGHUP` to be present. But how did that process got other masks? Did `ssh` added them? How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

I got the above snippet working as expected by using `trap "" HUP && exec` instead of `nohup`.

```
$ ssh blr-utubntu16x64-1 '{ trap "" HUP && exec tail -f ut.log &> /dev/null < /dev/null &} && echo $!'
```

```
$ ps -o pid,tid,ppid,pgid,sid,class,nice,rtprio,pri,sched,cmd,tty,tpgid,cgroup,stat,flags,sig,sigcatch,sigignore,sigmask,euid,ruid,egid,rgid,ouid -p 28679
  PID   TID  PPID  PGID   SID CLS  NI RTPRIO PRI SCH CMD                         TT       TPGID CGROUP                      STAT F          PENDING           CAUGHT          IGNORED          BLOCKED  EUID  RUID  EGID  RGID OWNER
28679 28679     1 28650 28650 TS    0      -  19   0 tail -f ut.log              ?           -1 12:pids:/user.slice/user-28 S    0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 28889 28889 10005 10005 28889
```

This process is being terminated as expected by using `kill` with `SIGINT`. But I still want to understand the behavior of `nohup`.